# How to set exec result to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, bash

How can I save an exec result to an array or a list, and show the result with PHP?

```
exec('./Script.sh');
```

---

This Script contains a list of IPs.

the content of the script is the following:

echo `nmap -sP 192.168.2.0/24 | cut -d "i" -f1 | cut -d " " -f2 | grep 192.168.2.*`

Thanks!

Comment: Try the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), specifically look at the second parameter.

Comment: do you really need an array or just the result as a string?

Comment: Hi @Pedro Lobito , I need a result as an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = [];
exec('./Script.sh', $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `shell_exec()` instead of `exec()`

```
echo shell_exec('./Script.sh');
```

This will output the result of `shell_exec()` as a string, if you really need an array, you can use `explode()` on line breaks:

```
$output = shell_exec('./Script.sh');
$outputArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $output);
```

---

[shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

> Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

Comment: Don't ask OP questions as answers. Use comments for clarification.

Comment: Hi @Rizier123, It was actually not a question, just a suggestion. Answer udpated.